# Denote properties of class to not be serialized

Tags: c#, silverlight, serialization, windows-phone-7, xml-serialization

I'm using silverlight on WP7.
I have a class I am trying to serialize to isolatedstorage. I know the framework will take care of serializing the class automatically for me, assuming every property is serializable.

For this class, I have some properties (such as BitmapImage) that are not serializable. Is there a way to tell the framework to NOT serialize that property (and instead, set it as null when it deserializes it?)

I know implementing XmlSerializable is a possibility, but I don't want to have to set/get each manually. I'd rather it serialize what I tell it to, and I can go and set the other properties after it has deserialized.

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [XmlIgnoreAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlignoreattribute.aspx) to tell XmlSerializer to ignore your property.

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for, thanks! PS - does it still call my constructor when it deserializes? :)

Comment: It calls default constructor (the one without parameters), when it deserializes.

Comment: By the way - I have a related question :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6172330/serializing-a-list-of-a-base-class