# XML serializing a list of a base class

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, windows-phone-7, xml-serialization

I have class `A` inherits from class `B`. I have a list of class `B` that contains `A` and `B` items:

```
List<B> myList = new List<B>();
myList.Add(new A());
```

When I try to serialize this list using `XmlSerializable`, an exception is thrown.  If I define the list to of type B, then I do not get this exception.  What is the best way to serialize the derived class?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[XmlIncludeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlincludeattribute.aspx#Y76) will do the trick.
If you go to this url, you will find a code sample there too.

Also, in the example the attribute is applied to the method, but you might want to apply it class A in your case.

Comment: Thanks again... you've saved me a huge headache. I've been stuck all day on a few weird aspects of serialization :)
one related note - since the serializable goes through calling the get on each public member - is there some sort of conditional get? I ask because I use it for binding as well, so my get/set change the properties and thus the second time it 'sets' (from deserializing) it isnt what was originally expected to go into the set

Comment: I would call it 'conditional accessors' (is that possible?)

Comment: Not sure I understood the question. On serialization it runs `get` on all your public properties (fields too). On deserialization it creates an object via default constructor and then calls `set` on each property.

Comment: If you mean if you can tell from code inside of `set` if it was called by serializer, I don't think there any standard ways to do it. With reflection you can, but I would recommend to use custom xml serialization instead.

Comment: I think what I'm actually looking for is the [OnSerializing] attributes... but the issue is I cant seem to get it to work on Windows Phone 7 :(